# How to minimize a prime ng dialog?

Tags: dialog, angular7, primeng

I would like to know how can I minimize a prime ng dialog box. I read [this](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/minMax.xhtml) but it is not working in Angular 7.

Also, as per their site [here](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dialog), the property **minimizable** is not present

Also I am using the dialogService of primeng. Is there any way that I can minimize the dialog and continue working.

Demo code for reference where I am using dialog service to open the angular component:

```
showPopup(header: string, groupName: string, controlName: string) {
const dialogRef = this.dialogService.open(StandardParagrahPopupComponent, {
  header: header,
  width: '60%',
  closable: true,
  data: {
    groupName: groupName
  }
});
dialogRef.onClose.subscribe(comments =>
  this.onPopupClose(comments, controlName)
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Minimize is not working in PrimeNG for Angular.
It is only working in Primefaces for JavaServletFaces.

The first link you provides leads to Primefaces Showcase, the second to PrimeNG showcase. So it is correct that on the second link you can´t find the minimize feature.